# Using "the" before a company name whose first word is "The"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am working on edits for a training manual that was sent to me.  The author consistently uses the word "the" before the company name, whose first word is "The."  Is this proper to use, or should "the" be deleted throughout?  Example:  "The Company abides by the [The Company Name] Code of Conduct established by [The Company Name], which is a manual of good company practices and behaviors. The [The Company Name] Code of Conduct is mandatory and violations can be punishable, up to and including termination."  Is it proper to use "the The..." together in this instance?  It just doesn't look right.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I believe this answers my question.  Have a great day!

Comment: @JasonBassford Except for the post-punk band [the The](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_The#:~:text=The%20The%20(%2F%C3%B0%C9%99%20%C3%B0,the%20only%20constant%20band%20member.) But there's always one...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it proper to use "the The..." together in this instance?

No, it is not proper. You'll never say a double preposition out loud like this, and even in writing it will mostly be frowned upon except in the most pedantic of settings (honestly, only lawyer documents come to mind).

It's even better if you rephrase your statements to avoid this entirely. Consider the following:

1. Under The Red Room Code of Conduct, it is illegal to ...
2. Under the The Red Room Code of Conduct, it is illegal to ...
3. Under The Red Room's Code of Conduct, it is illegal to ...

#1 and #2 is what you're debating to use. #3 avoids this entirely, because the possessive attaches the object in question (the code of conduct) to the entire proper name (The Red Room). There is no ambiguity here, and no repeated words.